# Save contents of Div in the state

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, reactjs

I am creating a restaurant menu. I have a modal appearing on click of each menu item of list. This logic uses innerHtml and paste the list content in the modal.

Now i want to save the content of this div separately in state of Menu Component, when clicking "OK" in modal. For example, in the first item list modal, i have Egg Drop, $2 and numeric input. I like to save Egg Drop in MenuItem  and  $2 in Price properties of Selected_Menu object. Also it will he more helpful if you can tell how to save Numeric Input value to Quantity.

```
 Selected_Menu:{

  MenuItem:null,
  Price:null,
  Quantity:null,
  TotalPrice:null
}
```

Please see the sandbox :
https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-feynman-mcyfo

Answer (score 0):

First thing to do is to pass in a function into the modal to update the menu's state.

```
 <NumericInput 
     onChange={value => this.setState({ [item]: value })} 
     /* -- snip -- *//
 />
```

This will update the count in the menu state for each item as the value changes. If you want this value to only be applied when the user clicks "Ok", then you will need to handle the state inside of the modal and only update the parent's (menu's) state when "Ok" is clicked. Which would look something like this:

```
 <NumericInput 
      onChange={value => this.setState({ count: value })} 
      /* -- snip -- *//
 />

 /* -- snip -- */
 <button onClick={() => this.props.setMenuItemCount(this.state.count)>
    Ok
 </button>
```

So to do it the second way, you'll need to create a new component for the modal that takes in a prop: setMenuItemCount. Where `setMenuItemCount` looks like this:

```
setMenuItemCount={count => this.setState({ [item]: count })}
```

Then you place this new component inside here:

```
<Modal.Body> 
    <YourComponent setMenuItemCount={count => this.setState({ [item]: count })}/>
</Modal.Body
```

Comment: Dylan thanks, but this is not exactly what i asked for

Answer (score 0):

Please check the https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-frog-m4dxf?file=/src/components/Menu.jsx.

So basically, since its a restaurant app, the purpose is to save the menu item, price and quantity into your database. so what can be done here is to maintain the current item in modal into your state, along with the quantity.
    Store it into state variable called Orders when "OK" button is clicked.

```
saveToOrders = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      this.setState({
        orders: [
          ...prevState.orders,
          {
            MenuItem: prevState.modalText.menuItem,
            price: prevState.modalText.price,
            quantity: prevState.modalText.quantity
          }
        ]
      });
    });
  };
```

where the state is represented as

```
state = {
    addModalShow: false,
    copied: false,
    modalText: {
      menuItem: "",
      price: "",
      quantity: 0
    },
    orders: []
  };
```